# Problem with connecting the Storage Domain (Host host2 cannot access the Storage Domain(s) <UNKNOWN>)

Tags: virtual-machine, storage, redhat, virtualization, ovirt

**Problem with connecting the Storage Domain (Host host2 cannot access the Storage Domain(s) )**

Hello, everyone! I need specialist help, because I'm already desperate. My company has four hosts that are connected to the storage. Each host has its own IP to access the storage, which means **host 1** has an ip `10.42.0.10` and `10.42.1.10` -> **host 2** has an ip `10.42.0.20` and `10.42.0.20` respectively. **Host 1** cannot ping the address `10.42.0.20`. Hardware I tried to explain in more detail. 
**Host 1** has ovirt node 4.3.9 installed and hosted-engine deployed.
When trying to add **host 2** to a cluster it is installed, but not activated. There is an error in ovirt manager - `"Host **host2** cannot access the Storage Domain(s) <UNKNOWN>"` and host 2 goes to "Not operational" status. On **host 2**, it writes "`connect to 10.42.1.10:3260 failed (No route to host)`" in the logs and repeats indefinitely. I manually connected **host 2** to the storage using iscsiadm to ip 10.42.0.20. But the error is not missing(. At the same time, when the host tries to activate it, I can run virtual machines on it until the host shows an error message. VMs that have been run on host 2 continue to run even when the host has `Non-operational` status.
I assume that when adding **host 2** to a cluster, ovirt tries to connect it to the same repository **host 1** is connected to from ip `10.42.1.10`. There may be a way to get ovirt to connect to another ip address instead of the ip domain address for the first host. I'm attaching logs:

***/var/log/ovirt-engine/engine.log***

```
2020-03-31 09:13:03,866+03 WARN  [org.ovirt.engine.core.dal.dbbroker.auditloghandling.AuditLogDirector] (EE-ManagedThreadFactory-engineScheduled-Thread-90) [7fa128f4] EVENT_ID: VDS_SET_NONOPERATIONAL_DOMAIN(522), Host host2.school34.local cannot access the Storage Domain(s) <UNKNOWN> attached to the Data Center DataCenter. Setting Host state to Non-Operational.
2020-03-31 10:40:04,883+03 INFO  [org.ovirt.engine.core.vdsbroker.vdsbroker.ConnectStorageServerVDSCommand] (EE-ManagedThreadFactory-engineScheduled-Thread-12) [7a48ebb7] START, ConnectStorageServerVDSCommand(HostName = host2.school34.local, StorageServerConnectionManagementVDSParameters:{hostId='d82c3a76-e417-4fe4-8b08-a29414e3a9c1', storagePoolId='6052cc0a-71b9-11ea-ba5a-00163e10c7e7', storageType='ISCSI', connectionList='[StorageServerConnections:{id='c8a05dc2-f8a2-4354-96ed-907762c29761', connection='10.42.0.10', iqn='iqn.2002-09.com.lenovo:01.array.00c0ff3bfcb0', vfsType='null', mountOptions='null', nfsVersion='null', nfsRetrans='null', nfsTimeo='null', iface='null', netIfaceName='null'}, StorageServerConnections:{id='0ec6f34e-01c8-4ecc-9bd4-7e2a250d589d', connection='10.42.1.10', iqn='iqn.2002-09.com.lenovo:01.array.00c0ff3bfcb0', vfsType='null', mountOptions='null', nfsVersion='null', nfsRetrans='null', nfsTimeo='null', iface='null', netIfaceName='null'}]', sendNetworkEventOnFailure='true'}), log id: 2c1a22b5
2020-03-31 10:43:05,061+03 ERROR [org.ovirt.engine.core.dal.dbbroker.auditloghandling.AuditLogDirector] (EE-ManagedThreadFactory-engineScheduled-Thread-12) [7a48ebb7] EVENT_ID: VDS_BROKER_COMMAND_FAILURE(10,802), VDSM host2.school34.local command ConnectStorageServerVDS failed: Message timeout which can be caused by communication issues
```

***vdsm.log***

```
2020-03-31 09:34:07,264+0300 ERROR (jsonrpc/5) [storage.HSM] Could not connect to storageServer (hsm:2420)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/vdsm/storage/hsm.py", line 2417, in connectStorageServer
    conObj.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/vdsm/storage/storageServer.py", line 488, in connect
    iscsi.addIscsiNode(self._iface, self._target, self._cred)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/vdsm/storage/iscsi.py", line 217, in addIscsiNode
    iscsiadm.node_login(iface.name, target.address, target.iqn)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/vdsm/storage/iscsiadm.py", line 337, in node_login
    raise IscsiNodeError(rc, out, err)
IscsiNodeError: (8, ['Logging in to [iface: default, target: iqn.2002-09.com.lenovo:01.array.00c0ff3bfcb0, portal: 10.42.1.10,3260] (multiple)'], ['iscsiadm: Could not login to [iface: default, target: iqn.2002-09.com.lenovo:01.array.00c0ff3bfcb0, portal: 10.42.1.10,3260].', 'iscsiadm: initiator reported error (8 - connection timed out)', 'iscsiadm: Could not log into all portals'])


2020-03-31 09:36:01,583+0300 WARN  (vdsm.Scheduler) [Executor] Worker blocked: <Worker name=jsonrpc/0 running <Task <JsonRpcTask {'params': {u'connectionParams': [{u'port': u'3260', u'connection': u'10.42.0.10', u'iqn': u'iqn.2002-09.com.lenovo:01.array.00c0ff3bfcb0', u'user': u'', u'tpgt': u'2', u'ipv6_enabled': u'false', u'password': '********', u'id': u'c8a05dc2-f8a2-4354-96ed-907762c29761'}, {u'port': u'3260', u'connection': u'10.42.1.10', u'iqn': u'iqn.2002-09.com.lenovo:01.array.00c0ff3bfcb0', u'user': u'', u'tpgt': u'1', u'ipv6_enabled': u'false', u'password': '********', u'id': u'0ec6f34e-01c8-4ecc-9bd4-7e2a250d589d'}], u'storagepoolID': u'6052cc0a-71b9-11ea-ba5a-00163e10c7e7', u'domainType': 3}, 'jsonrpc': '2.0', 'method': u'StoragePool.connectStorageServer', 'id': u'64cc0385-3a11-474b-98f0-b0ecaa6c67c8'} at 0x7fe1ac1ff510> timeout=60, duration=60.00 at 0x7fe1ac1ffb10> task#=316 at 0x7fe1f0041ad0>, traceback:
File: "/usr/lib64/python2.7/threading.py", line 785, in __bootstrap
  self.__bootstrap_inner()
File: "/usr/lib64/python2.7/threading.py", line 812, in __bootstrap_inner
  self.run()
File: "/usr/lib64/python2.7/threading.py", line 765, in run
  self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
File: "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/vdsm/common/concurrent.py", line 260, in run
  ret = func(*args, **kwargs)
File: "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/vdsm/executor.py", line 301, in _run
  self._execute_task()
File: "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/vdsm/executor.py", line 315, in _execute_task
  task()
File: "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/vdsm/executor.py", line 391, in __call__
  self._callable()
File: "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/yajsonrpc/__init__.py", line 262, in __call__
  self._handler(self._ctx, self._req)
File: "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/yajsonrpc/__init__.py", line 305, in _serveRequest
  response = self._handle_request(req, ctx)
File: "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/yajsonrpc/__init__.py", line 345, in _handle_request
  res = method(**params)
File: "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/vdsm/rpc/Bridge.py", line 194, in _dynamicMethod
  result = fn(*methodArgs)
File: "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/vdsm/API.py", line 1102, in connectStorageServer
  connectionParams)
File: "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/vdsm/storage/dispatcher.py", line 74, in wrapper
  result = ctask.prepare(func, *args, **kwargs)
File: "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/vdsm/storage/task.py", line 108, in wrapper
  return m(self, *a, **kw)
File: "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/vdsm/storage/task.py", line 1179, in prepare
  result = self._run(func, *args, **kwargs)
File: "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/vdsm/storage/task.py", line 882, in _run
  return fn(*args, **kargs)
File: "<string>", line 2, in connectStorageServer
File: "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/vdsm/common/api.py", line 50, in method
  ret = func(*args, **kwargs)
File: "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/vdsm/storage/hsm.py", line 2417, in connectStorageServer
  conObj.connect()
File: "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/vdsm/storage/storageServer.py", line 488, in connect
  iscsi.addIscsiNode(self._iface, self._target, self._cred)
File: "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/vdsm/storage/iscsi.py", line 217, in addIscsiNode
  iscsiadm.node_login(iface.name, target.address, target.iqn)
File: "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/vdsm/storage/iscsiadm.py", line 327, in node_login
  portal, "-l"])
File: "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/vdsm/storage/iscsiadm.py", line 122, in _runCmd
  return misc.execCmd(cmd, printable=printCmd, sudo=True, sync=sync)
File: "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/vdsm/common/commands.py", line 213, in execCmd
  (out, err) = p.communicate(data)
File: "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/subprocess32.py", line 924, in communicate
  stdout, stderr = self._communicate(input, endtime, timeout)
File: "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/subprocess32.py", line 1706, in _communicate
  orig_timeout)
File: "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/subprocess32.py", line 1779, in _communicate_with_poll
  ready = poller.poll(self._remaining_time(endtime)) (executor:363)
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I'm struggling trying to figure out your architecture. It seems like you've configured your Storage Domain pointing to 10.42.1.10:3260 as iSCSI portal.

If I've understood correctly, your cluster should be something like:

```
     +-------------+
     |HostedEngine |
     +------+------+
            |
            |         Management network
    +-------+------+  10.42.0.0/24
    |              |
    +              +
10.42.0.10    10.42.0.20
+--------+    +--------+
| host1  |    | host2  |
+--------+    +--------+
10.42.1.10    10.42.1.20
    +              +
    |              |
    +-------+------+
            |
            |        Storage network
        +---+---+    10.42.1.0/24
        |Storage|
        +-------+
```

Provided my guess is correct, it seems you've configured your iSCSI target on **host1** instead of a proper, external, storage device. Otherwise, you've messed up with IP addressing.